# A question about sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

Could someone please help me  with sed to change this line global in the document:

```
432 |---|1 M a n y - w o r d s !|---| (123.WORDS)
```

To:

```
432 |---|1.M.a.n.y.-.w.o.r.d.s.!|---| (123.WORDS)
```

Comment: Is this the exact line or can the number, the "many words" and the term in parenthesis vary?

Comment: Why sed and not something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sed` command:

```
sed 's/\s/./g;s/432./432 /;s/!|---|./!|---| /' source.txt
```

And of course you can do the `substitution` in place with `sed -i` or send it to another file with `sed ... > output.txt`

`g`: global option

Comment: Instead of piping to another instance of `sed` you should better do all in one script: `sed 's/\s/./g;s/\./ /;s/!|---|./!|---| /' source.txt`. Using option `-i` won't work with the piping anyhow. And when changing back the first whitespace you don't need to limit it to number 432. And the `g` option is superfluous for the second and third `s` command.

Comment: Thank you is working but will not do for my sed equation and its my fault since i didn't explain exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change all whitespaces between the two occurences of `|---|` with dots, use

```
sed 'h;s/ /./g;G;s/.*\(|---|.*|---|\).*\n\([^|]*\).*|\(.*\)/\2\1\3/'
```

1) You save the original line in the hold buffer with `h`
2) You replace all spaces with dots with `s/ /./g`
3) You append the original line from the hold space with `G`
4) THe last `s` command composes the final line out of the middle part with replacements and first and last bit without replacements.

Comment: Im surprised since i only know the basics of SED  thank you but will not do for my sed equation and its my fault since i didn't explain exactly my real problem pls take a look to my actual problem that giving me a headache for days  search for "How junk letters can be removed from a document with SED?"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Perl rather than sed:

```
perl -naF'/\|/' -e '$F[2] =~ tr/ /./; print join "|", @F'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the @F array
- `F '/\|/'` uses the literal vertical bar as a delimiter when splitting
- `$F[2]` contains the 3rd column
- `tr` is the transliteration operator, it replaces spaces with dots in the third column
- `join` connects the columns of the array back (see [join](http://p3rl.org/join))

Comment: Thank you but i want to do this only with sed

Comment: Good luck, I prefer to use the right tool fot the job.